# Eclipse Tasks View - how to customize markers?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

The Eclipse Tasks (and Code Markers) seems elusively challenging to customize.

**Question**

How do you add custom tags to the Tasks filter? e.g. maybe I want to add "Super-Bug" or something.

**Example**

Currently I know empirically that you can use todo, fixme & xxx; and they are case-insentive. here is example.

[image]

This is one of those questions you would think should take 1min + Google-Searching + Manual; but then eventually after 10minutes you give up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add your custom task tags. Click `Window > Preferences`. Go to `C/C++ > Task Tags`. You will get a preference page as shown below.

[image]

Note that you can choose **Case sensitive task** as shown in pic in point no 7.

After adding your tag. Crate a C project and try to add this tags in c or cpp file.
Example shown below.
[image]

Note:

1. You can add task manually by right clicking on the line number column of an editor and choosing `Add task...` option. These task will appear in **Task** category as shown above.
2. Task added in c/cpp editors will appear in `C/C++ category`
3. In Task view menu choose `Group by` type.